# Exchange Web Services Item copy return null

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server

I'm trying to copy a Contact (Item) from MailBox to Another (for backup). 
Every time i copy i want to now the new one item ID that i had just create.

There is the code:

```
Contact item = contact.Copy(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new Mailbox("destiny@destiny.com"))) as Contact;
```

The problem is => `item = null` !!!

Is the Copy function async?

how I get the ID of my copy?

It sounds to be a SDK bug, because in MSDN website documentation the XML response comes with item ID...

Any Ideas?

Comment: If the as function is returning null is because the object returned by the Copy function is not assignable to the Contact type.  I would check the returned type using the .GetType() method and make sure it is the type you are expecting.

Comment: the return type is a Item, and a Contact is a extense of a Item. But if you put: var item = ... -> returns null...

Comment: does the copy method still return null even without the cast?  If so, perhaps the method is failing to create the copy of the contact in the mailbox.

Comment: just adding a link to the documentation for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact_members(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Done!

**Answer:** `contact.copy(destiny) ->` Destiny must be the same Contact folder. After copy I use `.move` to move to other folder.